# Grant Imported Privileges to A Role for Data Share

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, share

I need to grant imported privileges to a role on a data share.

I am new to Snowflake and I don't have experience using data shares, but I am referencing the [share documentation](https://stackoverflow.com).

For context, there are 5 tables that were re-up uploaded to the data share. I was asked to grant imported privileges to the DATA_SCIENTIST role.

Per the email (where xxx_s is the data share name):

```
I have added the tables below to the data share xxx_s.
 
GRANT SELECT ON table XXX.XXX.<table1> xxx_s;
GRANT SELECT ON table XXX.XXX.<table2> xxx_s;
GRANT SELECT ON table XXX.XXX.<table3> xxx_s;
GRANT SELECT ON table XXX.XXX.<table4> xxx_s;
GRANT SELECT ON table XXX.XXX.<table5> xxx_s;
```

I have tried :

```
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATA EXCHANGE xxx_s TO ROLE data_scientist;
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE xxx_s TO ROLE data_scientist;
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATA SHARE xxx_s TO ROLE data_scientist; /*invalid syntax*/
```

I also tried granting privileges to each table like:

```
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON TABLE XXX.XXX.<table 1> data_scientist;
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON TABLE XXX.XXX.<table 2> data_scientist;
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON TABLE XXX.XXX.<table 3> data_scientist;
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON TABLE XXX.XXX.<table 4> data_scientist;
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON TABLE XXX.XXX.<table 5> data_scientist;
```

In all cases, I encounter an error that the data exchange or database does not exist, but when I use:

```
SHOW SHARES;
```

The data share is listed.

This seems like a simple task, but I have been unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If additional information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: So have you actually created a database from the share in the consumer account?

Comment: I have not created a database from the share, but the tables exist in the current database, so I assumed this was already completed. Do I need to make a database?

Comment: Just to clarify, did you have an existing Share from which you has already created a Database in the consumer account? You then changed, in some way, the tables assigned to the Share? If that's the case then you shouldn't need to do anything - the tables will automatically appear in consumer DB and whatever role already had access to that DB will be able to see any new tables you've added to the share

Comment: Yes, that is correct it. The Share is existing and a database has already been created. 5 tables within the database were re-uploaded yesterday.

Oh, thank you. I was told that I need to grant imported privileges by a co-worker who is on vacation. Is there a way to confirm that the necessary role has the correct privileges to use the data?

Comment: Use the role and query for the data? Check what privileges have been granted to the role?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like they do not have privileges for the tables. As ACCOUNTADMIN, I tried GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATA EXCHANGE xxx.xxx.xxx TO ROLE data_scientist; the error I receive is: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are introducing Data Exchanges as they've got nothing to do with this, based on the information you've provided. All you need to do is run GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE xxx TO ROLE data_scientist; assuming this hasn't been run previously

Comment: Thanks for that detail. It worked finally. Thank you do much!